# creating a matrix in matlab with Hankel command

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am a bit confused on how to construct a matrix using the `henkel` command. I have read from mathworks the description of the command however I want to do the following:

Assume we have a vector `v = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 .. 400 ]`

and I want my matrix to have the following form:

```
    v(4)  v(3) v(2) v(1)
    v(5)  v(4) v(3) v(2)                
A = v(6)  v(5) v(4) v(3)
    v(7)  v(6) v(5) v(4)
    v(8)  v(7) v(6) v(5)
ets
```

I have tried experimenting with a vector. For example:

```
A = hankel(v,vec);
```

where `vec = [1,2,3,4]` or `vec = [4 ,3 ,2 ,1]`

but it did not work. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

`hankel` keeps anti-diagonal elements equal. You need too call `hankel` first to construct the flipped matrix, then you can flip it calling `flipdim`. Try this:

```
v = 101:500; % just a sample vector of values
c = 1:396;
r = 396:400;
I = flipdim(hankel(c, r), 2); % indices of values in v
A = v(I)
```

Take a look at this simpler example to see how these work:

```
v = 11:18;
c = 1:6; % the first column of the hankel matrix (H)
r = 6:8; % the last row of the hankel matrix (H)
H = hankel(c, r)
I = flipdim(H, 2)
A = v(I)
```

> ```
> H =
>
>      1     2     3
>      2     3     4
>      3     4     5
>      4     5     6
>      5     6     7
>      6     7     8
>
>
> I =
>
>      3     2     1
>      4     3     2
>      5     4     3
>      6     5     4
>      7     6     5
>      8     7     6
>
>
> A =
>
>     13    12    11
>     14    13    12
>     15    14    13
>     16    15    14
>     17    16    15
>     18    17    16
> ```